# One Click at .click(function() Not Working in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to open another page on my site with this ajax:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onclick="$(this).click(function(){$(this).html(loadE);$(this).load('http://domain/page2 #idContent')});">OPEN</div>

<script>
var loadE = "<img src='data:image/gif;base64,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' alt='Loading'/>Loading..";
</script>
```

But these pages can only be loaded with a double-click. What is wrong in my code, can you help me? thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this and it will work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        var loadE = "<img src='data:image/gif;base64,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' alt='Loading' />Loading..";

        $("#myDiv").click(function(){
            $(this).html(loadE);
            $(this).load('http://domain/page2 #idContent');
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="myDiv">OPEN</div>
```